# How to compare two javascript variable values defined in two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two javascript functions like below which wll count the non-blank lines from textareas.

HTML:

```
<div id="map-devlist" >
    <div class="block-with-text-area">
    <div class="input-quest-with-text-area">Enter your device list(one device in one line)</div>
    <div class="input-resp-with-text-area"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="devs" name="devs" type="text" onkeyup="devscount();"></textarea></span> </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="lunidlist" >
    <div class="block-with-text-area">
        <div class="input-quest-with-text-area">Enter your LUN IDs in Hex(one ID in one line)</div>
        <div class="input-resp-with-text-area"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="lunids" name="lunids" type="text" onkeyup="luncount();"></textarea></span> </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div id="error1"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function devscount()
{
    devcounts = 0;
    var lines = $("#devs").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) devcounts++;
    }
}   

function luncount()
{
    luncounts = 0;
    var lines = $("#lunids").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) luncounts++;
    }

    if(devcounts == luncounts) {
        var message ="both counts are matching";
    } else {
        var message ="Mismatch between values";
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=message;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to compare the line count on these two textareas and if they are equal and not equal I need to display a message. But the above script not working for me. When I echo  `document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=devscount;`  and  `document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=luncounts;` on their corresponding function, it showing the line count perfectly. But I am not able able to compare their values. how to do that ?

[**JSFIDDLE SETUP**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/)

Comment: Since the variables  are included in the functions, they won't see each other, if you declare them outside the 2 functions, you can compare them, as they will be in the same scope

Comment: `if(devcounts() == luncounts())`

Comment: Make the variables global and set their values inside functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your jsfiddle wasn't just the question alone.  There was also an issue with the way you were trying to check the values.  The 2 text areas were running the functions to count items in them, on keyup, but not running the comparison code.  I changed them both to run a 3rd function, `checkcounts`, and modified the script to this...

```
var devcounts;
var luncounts;

function devscount() {
    devcounts = 0;
    var lines = $("#devs").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) devcounts++;
    }
}   

function luncount() {
    luncounts = 0;
    var lines = $("#lunids").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) luncounts++;
    }
}

function checkcounts() {
    devscount();
    luncount();

    var message;

    if(devcounts == luncounts) {
        message ="both counts are matching";
    } else {
        message ="Mismatch between values";
    }

    document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=message;
}
```

**[Working jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/7/)**

Comment: I have tried the first method. but it doesnt show the message. please have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/4/

Comment: I've fixed what you had in the jsfiddle.  As well as your question here there were a few other issues, like not actually comparing the counts on textarea keyup.  Here's a working version... http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/7/

Comment: thanks it worked. Is there anyway I can hide the message until and unless I enter data on both boxes ? here as soon as i enter value in first column it showing error message

Comment: Just remove the `onkeyup` handler from the first text area.  You could use `onchange` or `onblur` for the second text area as well, so it only checks when you leave it.

Answer (score 2):

It strikes me that you are writing an awful lot of code to do something very very simple.  I have replaced your code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/3/).  A single function

```
function testCounts()
{
 var devCounts = $('#devs').val().split('\n').length;
 var lunCounts = $('#lunids').val().split('\n').length;
 var equals = (devCounts == lunCounts)?'Equal':'Not Equal';
 $('#error1').text(equals);
}
```

Or am I getting this entirely wrong.

Comment: if i put value in first code it displaying equal eventhough the second textarea empty..

Comment: That is an entirely unrelated issue.  You need to strip out the empty strings in the array created from the text area content.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgGAZ/6/)